How do I create nodes and edges in Neo4j
I am trying to create nodes and edges from a CSV file, in Neo4j, nodes appeared but edges were not created
I used this:
Create nodes in Neo4j
@staticmethod
def _create_nodes_batch(tx, batch):
    query = """
UNWIND $batch AS node
CALL apoc.create.node([node.type], 
    CASE node.type
        WHEN 'Station' THEN {number: node.start_station_number, name: node.start_station}
        WHEN 'Bike' THEN {number: node.bike_number}
        WHEN 'Member' THEN {type: node.member_type}
        WHEN 'Trip' THEN {duration: node.duration, startDate: node.start_date, endDate: node.end_date}
    END
"""
    tx.run(query, batch=batch)

Create edges in Neo4j
@staticmethod
def _create_edges_batch(tx, batch):
  
    query = """
     UNWIND $batch AS edge
MATCH (a:Trip {id: edge.source}), (b:Station {name: edge.target})
CALL apoc.create.relationship(a, edge.relationship, {}, b)
YIELD rel AS createdRelationship
RETURN createdRelationship

"""
    tx.run(query, batch=batch)


Does the second Cypher query work with the same batch data when you try it out in the Neo4j Browser?

yes, the query worked

Your question needs to show all relevant code, not just 2 isolated functions. Also, to suss out any issues with your overall approach, test a simple function that just prints the result of the Cypher query "RETURN 1 AS result" to see if that works. If not, debug.
